# Can I use embedded Ruby in I18n locale files in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Like the following sample code:

```
models:
   mymodel:
     description: it has <%= Arbitrary::Ruby::Code::Inside.and_a_variable %>
```

So `t('models.mymodel.description')`, given the following:

```
module Arbitrary
 module Ruby
  module Code
   class Inside
     def self.and_a_variable
      'a variable'
     end
   end
  end
 end
end
```

Would result in:

```
'it has a variable'
```

Just out of curiosity, is something similar to this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes** and **no**.

The simple answer is no - the I18n gem does not have a built-in ERB loader in the Simple backend. Nor does it pass any other type (YAML or JSON) through ERB like Rails does with some configuration files.

It does have a built in `.rb` loader. Which really can be used to do anything as long as eval'ing the content results in a hash:

```
# config/locales/en.rb
{ 
   en: {
     hello: "dlroW olleH".reverse
   }
}
```

```
# config/locales/fr.rb
# lets go crazy and load a translation file from a remote server
require 'json'
require 'net/http'

res = Net::HTTP.get_response(
         # does not actually exist
         URI('http://www.example.com/locales/fr.json')
      )
JSON.parse(res.body)
```

It is also probally possible to create a loader method that would pass `locales/*.erb` files through `ERB`:

```
module ErbLoader
  def load_erb(filename)
    begin
      template = ERB.new(File.read(filename))
      context = binding
      YAML.parse(template.result(context))
    rescue TypeError, ScriptError, StandardError => e
      raise InvalidLocaleData.new(filename, e.inspect)
    end
  end
end

I18n::Backend::Simple.include(ErbLoader)
```

See [I18n::Backend::Base#load_file](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/blob/f19ee0de1320671856dbc4375ab3f2716d13f03a/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb#L223) for an explaination of how this works.

You could also create your own backend which passes `.yml` files through ERB. The I18N gem is really built from the ground up to be extended through different backends for storing translations.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful information. I will keep this in mind in case I need this in the future. The backend approach seems totally legit.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. It is not possible. You only inject values, it does not actually run `ruby` code.